# Vertically center text together with an image in a button

Tags: html, css, image, button

It's pretty simple, I have a button, I want an icon to the left of it. The problem is that the button text is pushed downwards a little, so the icon and the text don't line up neatly. I'm not really sure what causes this, I tried vertical-align and setting the line-height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKlFb

### HTML

```
<button>
  <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/16/3995/3995186.png"/>OBS
</button>
```

### CSS

```
button {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 27px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: check out Font Awesome, I know it doesn't answer your question, but I always find it difficult to align images with text, and font awesome icons align perfectly

Comment: @SamCreamer I know about font-awesome. I'm just not going to install a huge library (or strip it down completely) for something as simple as one button with an icon. It's like using jQuery when all you have to do is add an eventListener to one button.

Comment: your point is well taken

Answer (score 2):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/TnLs8/)

Try following:

```
<button>
   <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/16/3995/3995186.png" alt="" class="icon"/>
   <span>OBS</span>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button img,
button span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Editted:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jats_ptl/TnLs8/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Just float your image to the left and it should be fixed:

**HTML:**

```
<button>
  <img src="http://img.informer.com/icons/png/16/3995/3995186.png" alt="" class="icon"/>
  OBS
</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 27px;
}

button > .icon
{
  float: left;
}
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klmwH)